# How to ssh into an EC2 without using the .pem file (Windows)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I want to ssh into an EC2 instance without using the .pem file on Windows.
Instead of using 
`ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@public-dns-hostname` 
like described in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html), i would like to use
`ssh ec2-user@public-dns-hostname` 
I read that you need to change the permission of the .ssh directory, but how exactly can I do that for Windows?
What is the best solution for my problem?

Thank you :)

Comment: Which version of Windows? Which SSH client?

Comment: Windows uses RDP for remote access. Have you installed an SSH server on Windows? If yes, then configure SSH password login.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a `~/.ssh/config` file.  For example:

```
Host ec2-ip-or-dns-name
 User ec2-user
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 Port 22
 IdentityFile c:/path/to/my-ec2-key.pem
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

With this configuration, you can simply do `ssh ec2-ip-or-dns-name`, without specifying the user or the `.pem` file.